# Edit current query to get info from one database in a Picklist of 4 db

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query running in a report with a picklist of 4 seperate Databases. It is running fine, but I need to exclude all transactions in one of the databases, before a certain period.

How can I add to this query, that will allow this, say I have DBa, DBb, DBc and DBd - and I want all transactions before period 35 on DBa to be ignored, but still include this info for the remaining 3 DB?

```
SELECT 'Actual'[Type],
               RTRIM(Entities.Name) AS 'CompanyName',
               gl.accountlink,
               gl.Master_Sub_Account, (sum(debit)-sum(credit))[Opening Balance]
FROM _bvgltransactionsfull glt
INNER JOIN _evGLAccountsFull gl ON glt.AccountLink = gl.AccountLink
INNER JOIN _etblperiod p ON p.idperiod = glt.period
LEFT JOIN [Entities] ON 1=1
WHERE glt.period < @PeriodStart@
  AND isBSAccountType = 1
GROUP BY Entities.Name,
         gl.accountlink,
         master_sub_account
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Opening',
       RTRIM(Entities.Name),
       accountlink,
       Master_Sub_Account,
       AccumActual
FROM _evGLAccountsAnnualOpeningBalances
LEFT JOIN [Entities] ON 1=1
```

Answer (score 1):

[DB_NAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/db-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) will return the current connected database name. You could apply a filter on `DB_NAME()` on your query, assuming that you change your current connection before issuing each query:

```
SELECT 
    'Actual'[Type],
    RTRIM(Entities.Name) AS 'CompanyName',
    gl.accountlink,
    gl.Master_Sub_Account, 
    (sum(debit)-sum(credit))[Opening Balance]
FROM 
    _bvgltransactionsfull glt
    INNER JOIN _evGLAccountsFull gl ON glt.AccountLink = gl.AccountLink
    INNER JOIN _etblperiod p ON p.idperiod = glt.period
    LEFT JOIN [Entities] ON 1=1
WHERE 
    glt.period < @PeriodStart@
    AND isBSAccountType = 1

    AND 
        (
            DB_NAME() <> 'DBa' OR
            (DB_NAME() = 'DBa' AND /*Transactions after period 35*/)
        )
```

Comment: Thank you. The program I use runs the script for all 4 databases and then loads the results in excel. I don’t actually change the connection each time. Essentially what I need the script to do is handle each DB’s parameters (for the three they will run without any further parameters, the one, as above, will have a parameter on the period).

Comment: @GrayMeiring How is the program running the script on 4 different databases without adding the 3-part object convention (`DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName`) and without changing the current database? One thing is the login connection (once per Server) and another thing is the currently connected database. You can switch currently connected database using the `USE DatabasName` statement while keeping the same connection.